# How to add shortcode to html widget

Tags: shortcode, widgets

I'm trying to include a shortcode to an html widget by adding below code to `functions.php`

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'shortcode_unautop'); 
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

and to the html widget `<script>alert("'" + [user_email] + "'");</script>`

but it keeps saying `user_email` is not defined.

Comment: edit your question to show us the exact HTML code you use in the widget.

Comment: If the filter didn't work, it would just print the text. But apparently it does work, because you get an error message.The problem seems to be that the shortcode is ill defined.

Comment: yes it was.  thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to do is drag & drop a Text widget to your WordPress sidebar on the Appearance » Widgets screen in your dashboard. After adding the widget, you can simply add your shortcode inside the text edit area of the widget.

[image: Follow these step]